Colourising rgb and rgba colours outside css
I've been looking at colorful-mode and rainbow-mode, but they only seem to colourise #rrggbb in every buffer, not rgb(rrggbb) or rgba etc. Is there a way to tweak these to get that working?
I saw this as a feature request in colorful-mode, but they described it as out of scope, why would that be?
